# Running script on startup and after switching network

Tags: shell-script, fedora, networkmanager

I'm using Fedora 26, and I'm trying to create a script that will change my MAC address every time I reboot, and I switch networks/turn the network manager off and on. I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo service NetworkManager stop

sudo ifconfig wlo1 down

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
  echo "wlo1"
  sudo macchanger -r wlo1
  echo " "
  echo "eno1"
  sudo macchanger -r eno1
  echo " "
  echo "============================="
  echo " "
done

echo "Final MAC "
echo "wlo1"
sudo macchanger -r wlo1
echo " "
echo "eno1"
sudo macchanger -r eno1

sudo service NetworkManager start
sudo ifconfig wlo1 up
```

And it works nice, but I need to run it manually. I tried running it on login by editing the .bash_profile file, but it prompts for a password in the background, behind the gui. I saw it when I turned the machine off with the power button. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Is there like an event for network manager being turned off, so i can fire it up then automatically? + can I make it show me a notification that it's changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your script in `/etc/profile.d/` folder. The scripts placed there are run at login. Since your script has `sudo`, you can use `-S` flag to make `sudo` accept password from standard input. You can use:

```
echo "ur P@ssw0rd" | sudo -S UrCommand
```

Comment: Yea just found it here https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line Thanks!

Comment: By the way. Any idea how to make the script run on network change and on kill of network manager?

Comment: Keeping passwords in plaintext is rarely a good idea. You can configure `sudoers` for `sudo` not to require password for certain commands/users.

Comment: Can you show me an example? I was going to set it so that only root can see and edit the file

Comment: yes @sebasth even i'm thing the same thing and wondering about a workaround

Comment: Some eamples are provided in [ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#Common_Tasks). Documentation in [`man 5 sudoers`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) also has [examples](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/sudoers.5.html#contenttoc8).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a different MAC per boot, I'd do instead

`nmcli connection modify "$NAME" wifi.cloned-mac-address stable connection.stable-id '${BOOT}'`

See also, `man nm-settings`, https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/examples/nm-conf.d/30-anon.conf?id=66a09b21920679ade156ae6ed134476ddb73418a, and https://blogs.gnome.org/thaller/2016/08/26/mac-address-spoofing-in-networkmanager-1-4-0/

Comment: Can it be done on every connection to network?

Comment: Yes. You can override the default value, see the mentioned link to 30-anon.conf file as example